# spacy split sentences with abbreviations

Tags: python, spacy

spaCy splits a sentence incorrectly when there are dots for abbreviations.

```
import spacy
tool = spacy.load('en')
x = tool('It starts at 9:00 a.m. Eastern Standard Time.')
list(x.sents)
```

produces two sentences instead of one. How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Which model are you using sm, md or lg?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using the standard English models, `en_core_web_sm` or `en_core_web_md` or `en_core_web_lg`, the most common abbreviations like that one should be already handled:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
>>> doc = nlp('It starts at 9:00 a.m. Eastern Standard Time.')
>>> list(doc.sents)
[It starts at 9:00 a.m. Eastern Standard Time.]
```

However, if you have an abbreviation that is not recognized by the model you are using, you can use [`add_special_case`](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#special-cases) to handle it properly. For example in the following case, `Pres.` is not recognized as an abbreviation, therefore two sentences are returned instead of just one:

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
>>> doc = nlp('I want to talk to Pres. Michael')
>>> list(doc.sents)
[I want to talk to Pres., Michael]
```

You would have to load your own library of special cases in order to inform the model that this is an abbreviation, and not the end of a sentence. The verbatim text of the token ([`ORTH`](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes)) can be whatever you want, and may also include the dot.

```
>>> from spacy.attrs import ORTH, LEMMA
>>> nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('Pres.', [{ORTH: 'Pres', LEMMA: 'president'}])
>>> doc = nlp('I want to talk to Pres. Michael')
>>> list(doc.sents)
[I want to talk to Pres Michael]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following @augustomen 's anwser -- update for spaCy v3.5

loading the model from a shortcut is obsolete as of spaCy v3.0

```py
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
```

```py
>>> doc = nlp('I want to talk to Pres. Michael')
>>> list(doc.sents)
[I want to talk to Pres., Michael]
```

tokenizer cannot overwrite token's lemma, use norm instead

```py
>>> from spacy.attrs import ORTH, NORM
>>> nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('Pres.', [{ORTH: 'Pres.', NORM: 'president'}])
>>> doc = nlp('I want to talk to Pres. Michael')
>>> list(doc.sents)
[I want to talk to Pres. Michael]
```